# How do I get all images encoded in a xmp file?

Tags: c#, image

I have a file with have this general structure

JPEG file header -> exif -> xmp -> jpeg encoded image -> xmp -> jpeg encoded image. The problem is that I only get only the first image. I tried to get images from stream but the stream gets reset after each read.

```
Stream s = new FileStream(ofd.FileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var v = JpegBitmapDecoder.Create(s,BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
var v1 = JpegBitmapDecoder.Create(s, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

I want to get a light map from the new UltraHDR format google introduced pretty recently https://developer.android.com/media/platform/hdr-image-format . There exists a library for C++ but that will not be usable in c# app.